# Flutter with Springboot backend

Tags: flutter

Can we connect flutter with spring boot?

What version should use in url if we use android virtual device to connect with springboot backend?

what url use in cross origin springboot backend controller?

Comment: use Api to connect with backend services?

Comment: Yes. Can u share any sample?

Comment: the thing is at first you must create API using spring boot and then you can simply fetch data and connect your flutter app with your backend via API . to read and write or communicate with backend you can user flutter HTTP package. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: ok . I done like above samples . But if disconnect chrome browser, i have to change local port number for every time in backend cross origin. is there any default port for flutter as like angular port no : 4200?...

Comment: i am not clear on your requirement please explain to me.

Comment: one more doubt I have ... How to iterate values from database within column or row in grid view outside container ?

Comment: Hi @SaifulIslam ... once i run flutter using chrome . eg : localhost:53046 this generate for flutter . But after run using chrome, if i want to rereun , its generate another port number  so i have to change port number everytime in backend cross origin to connect with flutter. so is there any default port to run flutter in chrome?

Comment: how you could iterate value from database its depend on the structure of data and what data you are receiving.

Comment: I am using three column for app bar , product category and last column top products ... So I have to use column to display this. if use column or row , i am not able to iterate category name in grid view outside container... but i havent use column or row, iam able to iterate in grid view within body.

Comment: What solution for this? and default port number

Comment: // SingleChildScrollView(
        // child: SizedBox(
        // child:
        // Column(
        //   children: <Widget>[
 Container(
                    child: Center(
                       child: FutureBuilder(
                         future: loadList(),
                         builder: (context, snapshot) {

Comment: return category1List.length > 0 ? new Categorylist(
                               category1: category1List) :
                           new Center(child:
                           new Text('No data found, tap plus button to add!', style: Theme
                               .of(context)
                                .textTheme
                               .title));
                   },

Comment: check my above code... i have given this code within body

Comment: How to pass id in post function in api services in flutter? I am not able to pass id to create new address for particular login user id? Because id value take as null in createaddress url. so i am not to add new address in db for particular user

Comment: sorry brother its harder to solve problem without the actual context. sorry for helpless but I can suggest you that first of all learn how to use HTTP int flutter using HTTP package then try what ever you want;

Comment: How to pass id in post function in api services in flutter? I am not able to pass id to create new address for particular login user id? Because id value take as null in createaddress url. so i am not to add new address in db for particular user

Comment: can you tell me solution for above question?

Comment: yes. you can follow this link https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data or this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsT1pltLLX8

Comment: How to concatenate id in url in flutter ?                                                                    
 final Response response = await put(
     Uri.parse('http://localhost:8081/address/updateaddress/id'),
    
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(data),
    );

Comment: if i give like this in above code method, i am not able to do put function ... id take as null... so can u give me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Ya we can connect the backend with flutter using apis.

we have to create Rest controllers and return response in json format (Recommended)

here is the reference to connect it.
Article on medium [connect flutter to spring backend](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-data-in-flutter-using-spring-boot-rest-service-e722ceb80d97)

It's like, front end with flutter & backend with spring boot

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble connecting your Flutter application with your Spring-Boot server, check this out.

If you are running in an Android device, follow these steps.

1. Make sure that both devices are running in the same network (WiFi).
2. Check the IP of the laptop using `ifconfig` if running an Ubuntu.
3. Run the spring boot server on that IP instead of the usual localhost.
   For example, in the `application.properties`, you could have something like this that makes sure to run the server in the specified address.

```
    server.address=192.168.1.7
    server.port=8080
```

4. Allow the origin of the Flutter app to connect. For example, if running a WebSocket service, you would need the following

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/").setAllowedOrigins("http://192.168.1.5").withSockJS();
    }
```

where `192.168.1.5` is the IP of the Flutter. You can easily discover this from `Wifi > Advanced`.